# Select count with WHERE and OR but specifying a uniqueness

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi everyone I am in a problem.

I have a table that contains the job requests, which is called: `richieste`

Another table that contains the appointments which is called: `appuntamenti`

I have to count how many times the id of a worker, in this case the `57` is present when there is a join between the table: `richieste` and `appuntamenti`.

nothing easier.

```
$q_count_appto_manager = $connessione->prepare("
        SELECT count('ID_Richiesta')
        FROM richieste
        LEFT JOIN appuntamento
        ON richieste.ID_Richiesta = appuntamento.appto_id_richiesta
        WHERE operato_manager = ?
        OR operato_manager_capo_a_manager = ? 
        OR team_manager = ?
        OR team_manager_capo_a_team_manager = ?
        AND appuntamento.appto_stato = 'NC'
        ");
$q_count_appto_manager->bind_param("iiii", $pro,$pro,$pro,$pro);
$q_count_appto_manager->execute();
$r_count_appto_manager = $q_count_appto_manager->get_result();
$rcam=mysqli_fetch_array($r_count_appto_manager);
?>
<?php
if ($rcam[0] == 0) {
    echo $rcam[0];
} else {
    echo $rcam[0];
}
```

now the problem begins, the worker with id: 57, can have more positions within the table: `richieste`, as you can read from the query, in the `OR` part.

and as you can see from the image

[57 ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAuYJ.png)

so in this case the query will count every time the 57 is present in those positions, generating as output results: 4.

The problem is that I'm asking him to count 57 when he is in those positions, only when there is a join between the two tables, which as a true result should come out: 1

So it doesn't take the where condition into account as unique, but just counts how many times 57 exists in those positions.

How can I specify an attribute of uniqueness, limiting the query to count only when the 57 is in those positions and there is a join between the two tables?

Comment: Try `WHERE (operato_manager = ? OR operato_manager_capo_a_manager = ? OR team_manager = ? OR team_manager_capo_a_team_manager = ?) AND appuntamento.appto_stato = 'NC'`.

Comment: FYI: You are under impression that you are doing `LEFT JOIN` but it is not.`AND appuntamento.appto_stato = 'NC'` in WHERE clause is making it an INNER JOIN

Comment: @jarlh this work, write this answer and i marked to right, thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so you need to use parentheses:

```
WHERE (operato_manager = ? OR operato_manager_capo_a_manager = ? OR
       team_manager = ? OR team_manager_capo_a_team_manager = ?)
  AND appuntamento.appto_stato = 'NC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simpler to use `IN` with a single parameter:

```
WHERE appuntamento.appto_stato = 'NC' AND
      ? IN (operato_manager, operato_manager_capo_a_manager, team_manager, team_manager_capo_a_team_manager)
```